# unwanted HTTPS -> HTTP redirects with nginx + uwsgi + flask app

Tags: http, redirect, https, nginx, uwsgi

I have a [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) app, hosted by [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/), with [nginx](http://nginx.net/) as a reverse proxy to uwsgi, using the built-in [uwsgi proxy module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule).  Whenever I visit a page that redirects to another page, the Location header points to a non-HTTPS URL.  For example:

```
$ socat openssl:my-web-server:443 stdio
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: my-web-server

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: nginx/1.0.4
[...]
Location: http://my-web-server/login
```

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-web-server;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

uwsgi needs to be passed the scheme (http or https) used to serve the request in order to write the correct Location header.

By default a bunch of settings are set in the `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params` file.  The `include uwsgi_params;` line in the config file is what load these.

For whatever reason, though, the scheme is not one of these default settings.  This can be fixed by adding:

```
uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
```

to the nginx configuration after the `include uwsgi_params;` line, or by adding it to the `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params` file directly.